# JetBrains Web Strom IDE, not able to copy

Tags: ide, webstorm

I am not able to cut copy or do any thing with the shortcut keys, As the Commands are like "Meta + ", Ex: to Copy , usual or general command is "Ctrl + C", But here, it is showing as "Meta + C".
 Like wise, every command is Meta.

[image]

(NOTE: i am using free version of webstorm IDE)

Comment: Did you enable an alternate keyboard mapping? Change the keyboard mapping from preferences.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, thanks for the quick reply, "keyboard mapping from preferences", how to do, where i can find it

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) it should help you.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, Yes, after going through the link, and doing some experiments myself, i solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need changes keymap from webStorm . goto files->settings and it will open one dialog box in that keymap option you need to changes .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLZ0w.png)